# Angular - Get actual HTML element code rather than DOM generated element

Tags: angular, dom

I am working on fetching the actual Angular code for any HTML element clicked. For example:

```
<button (click)="getCode($event)" mat-button>CodeButton</button>
```

Using this code I can get the generated HTML in a similar way:

```
<button _ngcontent-buq-c44="" mat-button="">CodeButton</button>
```

However I would like to fetch the actual source code rather than the generated one. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to get the "uncompiled" html source code of the element? I don't really think that it would be possible. But anyway, for what exactly do you need that? I've never needed that case so far.

If I'd know the use case, there might be a better "workaround" for your situation.

Comment: I need it for showing code snippets in a page. I can use the actual html and then provide it as an HTML snippet. For example, https://react.ui.audi/?path=/story/components-accordion-variations--page when you click "Show code" for accordion you get the source of actual accordions rendered as html in a react snippet

Answer (score 0):

The template you write is not the actual HTML that browser uses to render the page. It is just an intermediate template syntax that angular provides which gets compiled to browser compatible HTML in the build process. So, i do not think there is a way to get the actual template written during development phase.

Answer (score -1):

You can use stackblitz for code snippets.